# How to avoid the generation of default jar when specifying a final name?

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles, maven-jar-plugin

We are using maven profile to build a jar specific to tomcat.

```
<profile>
    <id>TOMCAT</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-tomcat-${project.version}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

My expectation is to create a single jar with name **acme-tomcat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** but on building the project, maven is generating another one (a default one) **acme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**. How can we avoid the generation of the second one (acme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the build section in the profile section from

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-tomcat-${project.version}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

to

```
<build>
     <finalName>${project.artifactId}-tomcat-${project.version}</finalName>
</build>
```

helped me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I've only used Maven a few times to build projects, and I've generated WARs for Tomcat instead of JARs, but the process should be similar.

My build looks like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>sb</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The header at the top goes like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.majisto.socialbusiness</groupId>
    <artifactId>socialbusiness</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>socialbusiness</name>
```

I imagine if you switch the **packaging** row to **JAR** you should get one JAR file out of it.  The finalName in the build determines the filename and I think where you have it might be the confusing part to Maven.  Let me know if you have any other questions.  Maven made working with Spring so much easier.  Are you using "maven package" in the CLI?