# Running multiple maven profiles from command line

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles, maven-jar-plugin

have two profiles to build a dependent jar for a web application (one for tomcat and the other is for websphere). Here what I'm trying is to run those two profiles in one go to build those jars together.

```
mvn help:active-profiles -o -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install -PTOMCAT,WEBSPHERE
```

As a result of these executions we are expecting **acme-tomcat-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** and **acme-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar** but along with these a default jar is also being created **acme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**. It seems this because of the default execution.

How can we avoid this default execution to avoid the generation of default **acme-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**. We have referred a [couple of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697623/maven-multiple-profile-not-working) here in SO to arrive this and also we have [made a similar post earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297518/how-to-avoid-the-generation-of-default-jar-when-specifying-a-final-name) but which will not help us in this scenario.
Any pointers would be helpful.

## Profile configuration looks like

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>TOMCAT</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tom-jar</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-tomcat-${project.version}</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build> 
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.7.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jms-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.GA</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>WEBSPHERE</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>web-jar</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <finalName>${project.artifactId}-web-${project.version}</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build> 
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.3</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-jms-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.GA</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Thanks,
San

Comment: Could you please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101750/disable-the-execution-default-jar

Comment: Hi Thanks for the pointer, now I changed the execution id of my TOMCAT profile to <id>default-jar</id> to override the default execution. Now the pom works as intended. But is it the correct way?

Comment: The correct way is not using profiles to begin with actually. Why not have 2 separate projects: one tomcat specific and one websphere specific? Both inheriting from a common POM?

Comment: we are helpless in this regard as we are working on a legacy project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pointer from [Volodymyr Kozubal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2745622/volodymyr-kozubal), changed the execution id of my TOMCAT profile to:

```
<execution>
   <id>default-jar</id>
   .........
 </execution>
```

to override the default execution.

Thank you all